# Totaling Duplicate Records

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008

How can I total the duplicate records together?
Example:

```
1 John Doe $100.50
2 John Doe $51.23
Total Amount:$151.73
3 Jane Doe $100.01
4 Jim Johns $94.05
4 Jim Johns $5.00
Total Amount:$99.05
```

Can I make a new section on details and suppress it until records are duplicates?

Comment: What qualifies a record as a duplicate in this case? Are you asking how to make a group and summary?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like

```
var duplicates = from p in db.People
                 join p by p.Name into g
                 select new{g.Name, Sum => g.Sum(g.Price)};
```

Comment: I figured it out. thanks For your help guys.
I ended up making another detail section. Suppressed it until current record equals the same as the previous record.

Answer (score 0):

I would have Grouped by the NAME And then by PRICE. Then Hide The Name Group Header and the PRICE Group Footer. Add Name to the Price header and add a Total to NAME Footer.

This is a easy way to do it if you want to use grouping. That is if I understand your question correctly.